# I want to know if the codes below are working properly with debugging and visualization with a parallel program

Tags: python, debugging, parallel-processing

So this is the debugging code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def worker_function(index, results, lock, introduce_bug):
result = 0

# Introduce a bug - non-deterministic behavior
for _ in range(1000000):
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        result += 1
    else:
        result -= 1

# Introduce a bug - worker-specific bug
if introduce_bug and index == 1:
    print(f"Worker {index} has a bug! Division by zero.")
    result = result / 0  # Division by zero bug
    print(f"Worker {index} bug fixed!")

# Introduce a bug - occasional sleep to simulate varying execution times
if random.choice([True, False]):
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.5))

with lock:
    results[index] = result
    print(f"Worker {index} result: {result}")

def run_parallel_program(introduce_bug):
num_workers = 4
processes = []
results = multiprocessing.Array('i', num_workers)
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

for i in range(num_workers):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_function, args=(i, results, lock, introduce_bug))
    processes.append(process)

for process in processes:
    process.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()

print("All processes completed.")

return results[:]

class ParallelProgramGUI:
def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    self.root.title("Parallel Program Debugging and Visualization")

    self.introduce_bug_var = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    # Checkbox to introduce a bug or not
    bug_checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(
        self.root,
        text="Introduce Bug",
        variable=self.introduce_bug_var
    )
    bug_checkbox.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)

    # Button to start the parallel program
    start_button = ttk.Button(
        self.root,
        text="Start Parallel Program",
        command=self.run_parallel_program
    )
    start_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Matplotlib figure for visualization
    self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.root)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

def run_parallel_program(self):
    # Get the value of the introduce_bug checkbox
    introduce_bug = self.introduce_bug_var.get()

    # Run the parallel program
    results = run_parallel_program(introduce_bug)

    # Visualization
    self.ax.clear()
    self.ax.bar(range(len(results)), results)
    self.ax.set_xlabel('Worker Index')
    self.ax.set_ylabel('Result')
    self.ax.set_title('Results of Parallel Workers')

    # Draw the updated plot
    self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
root = tk.Tk()
app = ParallelProgramGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

and here is a code I'd like to test

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import random

def worker_function(index, results, lock):
result = 0

# Introduce a bug - non-deterministic behavior
for _ in range(1000000):
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        result += 1
    else:
        result -= 1

# Introduce a bug - worker-specific bug
if index == 1:
    result = result / 0  # Division by zero bug

# Introduce a bug - occasional sleep to simulate varying execution times
if random.choice([True, False]):
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.5))

with lock:
    results[index] = result
    print(f"Worker {index} result: {result}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
num_workers = 4
processes = []
results = multiprocessing.Array('i', num_workers)
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

for i in range(num_workers):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_function, args=(i, results, lock))
    processes.append(process)

for process in processes:
    process.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()

print("All processes completed.")
```

I want to know if the code is doing its job to debugg the code and provide visulization.
Also I want to make sure that the graph is properly displaying the debugging and that it is good visulization.

If there are any changes that need to be made please let me know and provide feedback please i would very much appreciate it!

Comment: the indentation is incorrect in the first piece of code.  python needs correct indentation.

Comment: also,  it is not clear what the actual error or problem is or the purpose of both pieces of code ?  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the problem is getting the first code to be able to debug parallel code with  the provided code and provide visualization and the indentation is incorrect due to me just copy and pasting it and just doing the required spacing for stack overflow.